# How to style this javascript countdown timer

Tags: javascript, html, timer

I've been following a tutorial on how to create a javascript countdown timer. I want to show each in a `<h1>` tag so i can style it with CSS, but all my attempts have failed so far, and honestly i have no idea on how to go about it. Any help is appreciated

Html

```
<span id="countdown"></span>
```

Javascript

```
// set the date we're counting down to
var target_date = new Date("Aug 15, 2019").getTime();

// variables for time units
var days, hours, minutes, seconds;

// get tag element
var countdown = document.getElementById("countdown");

// update the tag with id "countdown" every 1 second
setInterval(function () {

    // find the amount of "seconds" between now and target
    var current_date = new Date().getTime();
    var seconds_left = (target_date - current_date) / 1000;

    // do some time calculations
    days = parseInt(seconds_left / 86400);
    seconds_left = seconds_left % 86400;

    hours = parseInt(seconds_left / 3600);
    seconds_left = seconds_left % 3600;

    minutes = parseInt(seconds_left / 60);
    seconds = parseInt(seconds_left % 60);

    // format countdown string + set tag value
    countdown.innerHTML = days + "d, " + hours + "h, "
    + minutes + "m, " + seconds + "s";  

}, 1000);
```

Comment: countdown.innerHTML = "<h1>" + days + "d, </h1><h1> " + ...

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to use the  tag.  Style the span instead.

```
span#countdown {
    font-size: 48px;
    border: 3px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #ffe;
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/8mw6beqh/.

Answer (score 1):

Funny I'm working on the same thing. I used firstwatch's method, but wasn't able to target each individual method. Here's my finished [codepen](http://codepen.io/jbanegas/pen/ZGvaBR).

So I created individual variables for the different elements.

```
var daysTimer = document.getElementById("dayTimer");
var hourTimer = document.getElementById("hourTimer");
var minuteTimer = document.getElementById("minuteTimer");
var secondTimer = document.getElementById("secondTimer");
```

and made sure to run them separately

```
// format countdown string + set tag value
dayTimer.innerHTML = days;
hourTimer.innerHTML = hours;
minuteTimer.innerHTML = minutes;
secondTimer.innerHTML = seconds;
```

I used them in an unordered list as shown here:

```
<div id="clock">
  <ul id=time>
    <li id="dayTimer"></li>
    <li id="hourTimer"></li>
    <li id="minuteTimer"></li>
    <li id="secondTimer"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```